# Nginx always serves php-fpm site on domain1.com for any of the configured server blocks

Tags: php, nginx

I would like to serve two php sites and one static site on my server. Eventually I'd like to be able to add a number of further static, php or proxied sites to this nginx configuration.

At the moment, I try to serve

- `domain1.com` (php, WordPress)
- `sub.domain1.com` (php, phpMyAdmin)
- `domain2.com` (static, plain HTML)

However **all of the requests to any domain always end up serving domain1.com**. I have since implemented SSL, hoping to eliminate the wrongly served sites, however now they have turned into redirects to `https://domain1.com`.

I have also tried to implement a catch-all which drops the connection (`return 444`) on incorrect domains, but that does exactly what it says on the package: It'll just start sending empty responses for `sub.domain1.com` and `domain2.com`. Not sure what I expected to be honest.

Furthermore I have tried to move the `root` directive into location blocks as can be seen in `domain1.com`'s configuration, however this also did not help.

Additionally, I tried to put the domain in the `listen 80;` directives, such as `listen domain2.com:80` hoping to make nginx prefer this block over the general `domain1.com` block. I got that inspiration from [Nginx Request Processing Documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html). However, also without luck.

I would not call myself the most proficient nginx user, but on a different server which hosts multiple domains which serve proxied content from gunicorn servers, this was never an issue. Hence, I suspect the php related configuration part is what creates this problem.

The **guide** I used to set up my vanilla server was [this DigitalOcean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04). However, the server I am actually using is an Amazon EC2 t2.micro instance with all necessary ports opened in the security group. I am also using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Nginx is running as root, worker processes as www-data. The permissions are all set up like for `domain1.com` which is served without a problem. All the domains point to the IP address of the EC2 instance.

Thank you for helping!

This is my nginx configuration for each of the domains.

#### `domain1.com`

```
server {
     listen         80;
     server_name    domain1.com;
     return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain1.com;


    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;


    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    client_max_body_size 64M;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/domain1.com/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/domain1.com/public;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

---

#### `sub.domain1.com`

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    sub.domain1.com;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sub.domain1.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain1.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name sub.domain1.com;

    client_max_body_size 64M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        root /var/www/sub.domain1.com;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

---

#### `domain2.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;

    root /var/www/domain2.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: `nginx` version? How do you test is the site available (browser, version)?

Comment: Just a guess: try the main domain block last to give the sub-domains the opportunity to be matched first in case there is an order of precedence in the declaration of a server block

Comment: Thank you for your responses! @Jonathan I am a bit unsure what it means to try the domain block last. I assume you mean the `server name` block, but where should I put it to be last? Last as in at the end of the file? Or behind something else specific?

Comment: Assuming all your code is in one file, put the `server {}` block that contains the `server_name  domain.com` after the other `server{}` blocks that have `sub.domain.com` variants. Nginx probably doesn't work this way but if it does, the order of processing those blocks may be important

Comment: @LapshinDmitry I use Chrome 51.0.2704.84 on OS X. I also tried Safari and Firefox which yielded the same result. I use nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu).

Comment: @Jonathan Currently I have all of them in separate files. Should I move them to the same or would you recommend a different solution then?

Comment: Try putting them into the same file, and delete / backup the others

Comment: @ingr8 There is good CloudOcean article about SNI on Nginx, maybe it will help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: @Jonathan I have now tried putting all of the configurations in the same file. First `domain2.com`, then `sub.domain1.com`, then `domain1.com` and now `domain2.com` redirects to `sub.domain1.com` yielding a 404 and going directly to `sub.domain1.com` redirects to `domain1.com`.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/489801/nginx-rewrite-only-specific-servername-to-https try the idea solution there to redirect your unsecure to secure and update your question with a single file, properly formatted - at the moment it's too difficult to read